# Prevent Application.EnteredBackground after ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync

Tags: uwp

I'm implementing password protection in the app. To do that I'm showing additional view via ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(). To request password after sending app to background I'm using Window.Current.Activated event which I'm susbsribing in EnteredBackground. Hovewer this raises infiniteve loop of Window.Current.Activated/Application.EnteredBackground

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.EnteredBackground += OnEnteredBackground;
}

private int _mainId;

private void OnEnteredBackground(object sender, EnteredBackgroundEventArgs e)
{
    if (_mainId == 0 && CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().IsMain)
    {
        Window.Current.Activated -= Current_Activated;
        Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
    }
}

private async void Current_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.WindowActivationState != CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
    {
        Window.Current.Activated -= Current_Activated;
        if (CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().IsMain)
        {
            await ShowPasswordPromptAsync();
        }
    }
}

private async Task ShowPasswordPromptAsync()
{
    _mainId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;

    var passwordView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;
    await passwordView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;

            Frame frame = new Frame();
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            frame.Navigate(typeof(View.PINProtectionPage));
            // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
            Window.Current.Activate();
        });
    await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(newViewId, _mainId, ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions.SkipAnimation);
}

public async Task SwitchBackToMainViewAsync()
{
    var currentViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    if (_mainId != 0 && currentViewId != _mainId)
    {
        await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(_mainId, currentViewId, ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions.SkipAnimation);
        _mainId = 0;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to prevent `Application.EnteredBackground`, you can unregister event after `ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync`.

Comment: I how do I know whenever app goes background?